# Deserializing a JSON-collection(potentially with another collection) of objects in GSON

Tags: java, json, parsing, collections, gson

I've been fighting with JSON parsing using GSON today and a lot of things went well with a minimum amount of hassle.

Though, for the following JSON string I started running into some issues;

```
{"success":1,"response":{"dvds":{"IronMan":{"rating":"awesome"},"BatMan":{"rating":"awesome"},"Smurfs":{"rating":"childish"}}}}
```

In this JSON I have a collection "response" containing a collection of responsetypes. In the example the only responsetype included is dvds.
But my issue lies here; I wish to have every child of "dvds" to be parsed to a List response , each child being a single Dvd-class object (containing a String "title" and a String "rating")

Thus far parsing seperate values/objects and parsing arrays went with no real issues, but I can't wrap my head around how to solve parsing such collections.

googling today kept referencing me to "TypeTokens" but looking at the code in various topics regarding this issue, I still haven't understood how to implement it for my use-scenario at all.

So, to be concrete;
"How can I make GSON correctly recognize both my responsetype and dvd-collections?"

Currently my ResponseData.class looks like this:

```
public class ResponseData {
    public int success;

    public List<ResponseTypes> responsetypes;

    public class ResponseType{
        public List<Dvd> Dvds;
    }

    public class Dvd{
        public String title;
        public String rating;
    }
}
```

That's how i'd look at this problem in an array-based form, but this time i need to apply it in the case i run into a collection of objects instead. in all scenarios i can think of the Class of the object should be able to be recognized by the name of it's parent.

Currently the parsing is initiated as follows;

```
try{
    Gson gson = new Gson();
    Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(stream);
    ResponseData responsedata = gson.fromJson(reader, ResponseData.class);
    return responsedata;
}
```

I really hope someone can help me out! Thanks!

Comment: does that code even compile ? We can't have a public class nested in another.

Comment: Did you got your answer?

Comment: No sadly not, i made an example JSON string in the same hierarchy as I encountered however i did not supply this JSON.
In the end i ended up constructing a smal .php page on my own webserver which converted the JSON in another format (in the end also stripping quite some data i didnt use all off) so i could insert it right into my own function. In this case the JSON answers were also reduced from roughly 600Kb to about 180Kb. so that's profitable :)

Comment: In addition, I also made two small subfunctions in PHP which would fetch additional JSON data (which was stripped from the main answer) where needed in small bits (having cached the full JSON answer on last fetch as i will use the app in only a select small group, so that'll barely cost any disk space since it's for only 18-or-so client IDs)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you have here some problems:

1. the class `ResponseData` should hold `List<ResponseType>` and not `List<ResponseTypes>`
2. the json that you supplied isnt matching the classes above. 
   an accurate classes for this json are:

   ```
   public class ResponseData
   {
       public int success;
       public Map<String, Map<String, Dvd>> response;

       public class Dvd
       {
           public String rating;
       }
   }
   ```
3. in order to describe a list in json you should use: "[ ]". for example: [1,2,3]. you can read more about json [here](http://www.json.org/)
4. if you want the json to describe the class hierarchy you describe above. it should looks like:

   {"success":1,"responseTypes":[{"Dvds":[{"title":"IronMan","rating":"awesome"},{"title": "BatMan", "rating":"awesome"},{"title":"Smurfs", "rating":"childish"}]}]}
5. notice that unless you declare a mapping between the variable names and the json varible names then you should use the same names. for example "Dvds" and "responseTypes"